# How to store realtime websocket data on a cloud service

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to store the real time websocket data of a cryptocurrency exchange. The problem occured when i was storing this data to a csv file using pandas' `to_csv()` and `read_csv()` methods. As the file grows python couldn't catchup with the real-time data and is lagging way behind.

What could be the most optimal and cheap cloud service to store the websocket data and fetch it on demand?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using firebase to store each new entry with a query. you can also run a mysql or mongodb to send your data to.

If you don't want to implement a connection with db servers you can also use an sqlite database which is a database in a single file.